# How can I set how many levels to expand TreeView nodes?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

Doing this code will expand all the main nodes under root.

```
root
    images
    files
    docs
```

But I want to make that if I change it from 0 to 1 somehow to change the level so it will expand the next level.

```
root
   images
        myimages
   files
       myfiles
   docs
      mydocs
```

```
foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes)
{
    if (tn.Level == 0)
        tn.Expand();
}
```

I tried to add in the foreach:

```
if (tn.Level == 1)
    tn.Expand();
```

But that's not a solution.

Maybe I need `foreach` in `foreach`?

All this code is part of a method that is working under `BackgroundWorker` that get a list of my FTP server directories and files recursively.

So in real time while it's getting the directories and adding the nodes I want to expand the nodes level.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the data structure is recursive, IMHO the most appropriate way to deal with the issue is to traverse it recursively. Something like this:

```
void ExpandToLevel(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int level)
{
    if (level > 0)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
        {
            node.Expand();
            ExpandToLevel(node.Nodes, level - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
ExpandToLevel(treeView1.Nodes, 1);
```

That would expand just the first level. Pass 2 to expand the first two levels, etc.